# How do I save the current page data in html, css , javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Am trying to save the button the user creates, when the browser is refreshed.Meaning I want it to permanently stay there.

Here is a snippet of what am taking about:

```js
function create(){
  const a =  document.createElement("button")
  document.body.appendChild(a)
   const b = document.getElementById("buttoname")
   a.innerHTML = b.value
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Create a button</h1>
Button name:<input id="buttoname" type="text"><br>

<button onclick="create()">Create Button</button>

</body>

   
</html>
```

Thank for your help it means a lot.

Comment: Save that required info for that button in localStorage or cookies. Also share some code that you tried to solve this, will really enable other people to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `localStorage` - [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), you can save a variable there with the information for each created button. Then you need a function that will read the `localStorage` when the page loads and will create the described buttons